# Definition of "super clean"

Tags: word-meaning, idiomatic-language

On the Internet, my friend found this picture:

[image]

My question is how natural the expression "super clean cockpit" sounds to native speakers. What do you think?

My friend thinks this expression is awkward as the primary meaning of the word "clean" is "free from dirt, marks, or stains". I don't necessarily agree with him. Another meaning, is "simple/smooth" and here the word indicates something similar to the one in a phrase like "modern design with clean lines and a bright appearance".

The picture is made by a manufacturer in Switzerland for their fundraising campaign and a possibility is that their English is not perfectly natural.

https://www.indiegogo.com/projects/the-one-world-s-lightest-electric-folding-bike?utm_source=UCB%20Website%20DE&utm_medium=referral#/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "cockpit" is the area of an aircraft where the pilot(s) sit and from where the aircraft is controlled, similarly for the area in a car where the driver sits. "Clean cockpit" is a reasonable term, it encompasses good design with a lack of clutter or extraneous items in the cockpit. I would not expect the word "cockpit" to be used for a bicycle.

The word "appearence" in the picture should be "appearance".

Comment: Thanks! So, in essence, the phrase itself is not weird, even when "clean" indicates "simple", but using "cockpit" sounds wrong when we talk about a bicycle. Right?

Comment: Likewise the meaning of "puristic appearance" is unclear to say the least.

Comment: I see. Thank you guys for your help!

Comment: @KTDon agreed, cockpit sounds wrong for a bicycle.